# linq to sql classes no dbml

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I was wondering if it's possible to get the generated classes like a linq-to-sql class generates classes for every table without using the actual dbml. my situation is as following:

I have an api which gets all data from database and returns them as json.
on the other hand I have an application retrieving that data but it needs to be casted to the right classes again to work with it properly. Ofcourse I could write all those classes myself with the needed properties. But it would be handy if they could be generated. The application does not need any connection to the database itself. This is why I want to protect the database by not using a dbml. with a dbml, a connection is possible. So I just need those classes to cast the json to.

Can I do this or is it impossible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `T4` to generate the classes if that's what you need.
[Oleg Sych](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/09/t4-tutorial-creatating-your-first-code-generator/) has a good series of tutorials for this.

Hope it helps!

Comment: is it still supported? I think I read on it's page that it doesn't support VS2012 anymore?

Comment: Unfortunatelly I cannot answer that question. However, if it is not supported you can try another code-generation tool to create your classes.